# Set new defaults for PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to set default values for existing commands in PowerShell?
What I specifically want to do is to tell the `Get-ChildItem` command to show both normal and hidden files (`Get-ChildItem -Force`).

I know I can write a function where I can add this option and use whatever else is specified on the command line. But then I lose the auto-completion functionality for all parameters and options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do so using `$PSDefaultParameterValues`.  Has worked from 3.0+.

Microsoft's documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.1

Here is a set of examples directly from that documentation:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{"CmdletName:ParameterName"="DefaultValue"}

$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{ "CmdletName:ParameterName"={{ScriptBlock}} }

$PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"]=$True | $False
```